# Auto-deploy Zend Framework 2 application + Database schema + Actual data

Tags: database, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, web-deployment

**Background:**

I am using GitHub to store a ZF2 application.

The database schema + the actual data stored inside the schema are not being stored inside a version control.  At the moment I am in development mode, so I have some database dump scripts that I load into the database when I need to.  I also tweak entries in the database via phpMyAdmin when I need ongoing granular control for immediate testing purposes.  I am also looking into using Doctrire ORM, so my schema will be part of my code via Annotations, and that will be checked into GitHub.  Doctrine ORM will generate the actual schema for me, although it is still a separate step in the deployment process.  The actual data however, will still be outside of the application and outside of the repository and currently has to be dealt with separately and is not automated.

**Goal:**

I want to be able to deploy ZF2 application and the database schema, and the data onto Zend Server and have it "just work" in the most automated, least manual way possible.

**Question:**

> What is a recommended, best practice way to deploy every aspect of ZF2 application in the most automated, least manual way possible and have it "just work"?  Let's focus on the Development and Testing mode here, as in Production it may be good to have separate deployment steps to protect against accidental live data overwrites.

Comment: http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Zend-Framework-2-module-installer-td4661225.html

Comment: I checked it out, but I am not sure what I am to be looking for.  I didn't install the module yet, but if it will help me understand it, I will.  I would like to know more on what does it do exactly, before using it though.  It says it's a module for editing content, but I don't really need to edit content.  Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Phing (http://www.phing.info/) for deploying your PHP application, adjusting directory permissions, running database migrations, running unit tests, etc. I used Phing in couple of my projects with great success.